# Is there a way to get a list of defined languages in the project using ContentDelivery API in Kentico-Cloud?

Tags: kentico-kontent

I need to get a list of available languages for given project. It would like to use content delivery api to achieve this. Is that possible ?

Comment: Not at the moment, but it is something that should be coming to the product soon

Comment: Is the road map available somewhere publicly ? do you have a issue nr for this feature ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, right now there is no direct support in the Delivery API, however, there are some options.

At first, you can utilize the Content Management API to list variants of the [item](https://developer.kenticocloud.com/reference#content-management-api-v2-list-variants) or [content type](https://developer.kenticocloud.com/reference#content-management-api-v2-list-language-variants-of-content-type).

Secondly, you can create content type (and item) where you can list and maintain your languages and then request this item in your app.

At last, you can find Kentico Roadmap [here](https://portal.productboard.com/kenticocloud/tabs/4-under-consideration) and suggest/upvote requested feature(s).